In Next.js 14 what is the correct architecture approach for setting up dynamic routes when intercepting a particular slug?
Learning Next.js 14 I've been reading through the documentation on Dynamic Routes. If I'm targeting all pages in my site based on slug but I want to render something in particular for let's say a contact or about page which approach is accurate?
If my structure is:
app
  [slug]
    page.tsx
  /contact
    page.tsx
  /about
    page.tsx
  blog/[slug]
    page.tsx

the file system works. In some reading I've noticed that page a conditional is used so it the correct approach to do:
import {Fragment} from 'react'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

type Props = {
  readonly params: {
    slug: string
  }
}

export default async function Pages({params}: Props) {
  if (params?.slug === 'about') return <About />

  if (params?.slug === 'contact') return <Contact />

  if (params?.slug === null) return notFound();

  // async run query

  return // removed logic
}

so that would lead me to:
app
  [slug]
    page.tsx
    contact.tsx
    about.tsx
  blog/[slug]
    page.tsx

Research

Dynamic Routes
Parallel Routes
Intercepting Routes
How to implement redirects in Next.js

In Next.js 14 what is the correct file structure to handle pages that match a particular slug?

Manually implementing the special-case routes, as in the second example, seems odd to me; the first structure looks more idiomatic. Is there some problem with it?

Making sure I’m developing the intended direction. I think my brain hurts I’ve read through so much documentation

Taken from https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation

Apart from routing folder and file conventions, Next.js is unopinionated about how you organize and colocate your project files.

There is no hard-and-fast rule as to how you organize your project, NextJS leaves it up to you to decide based on your requirements.
The first approach seems to make sense to me because contact and about pages are not dynamic. If contact and pages are not dynamic, I don't think they should be part of [slug] routes.
The first approach's structure is also commonly used and understandable. I'd say this approach is better as it keep it simple, stupid (KISS principle).
The second approach can be confusing to other developers
app
  [slug]
    page.tsx
    contact.tsx
    about.tsx

On first glance, it seems to mean there are routes like
/subject-1, /subject-1/contact, /subject-1/about
/subject-2, /subject-2/contact, /subject-2/about
But in fact, there is additional code to control which component is rendered when /[slug] is accessed.
export default async function Pages({params}: Props) {
  if (params?.slug === 'about') return <About />

  if (params?.slug === 'contact') return <Contact />

  if (params?.slug === null) return notFound();

  // async run query

  return // removed logic
}

The above code is unnecessary because file-based routing would have already handled it elegantly (as in the first approach).
